# Settings not opening on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10, but I'm not able to open Settings.

> killall gnome-control-center

gives

> gnome-control-center: no process found

And also my laptop is hanging many times, I had to press the power button every time to restart.

```
gnome-control-center --verbose
```

gives

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

but `gnome-control-center --version`
gives `gnome-control-center 3.34.1`

Comment: Upgrade pain. In many cases, it is much better not to upgrade an existing install, but to freshly reinstall a new Ubuntu version.

Comment: Is there a way other than reinstalling?

Comment: What's the output of this command: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: @Gunnar  it say's  ubuntu:GNOME

Comment: I'm not convinced this is upgrade related. Having the same issue on my freshly installed 19.10 machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It also happened to me when I tried to open `Devices` section.

[Someone pointed out](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/dmkdo8/gnome_control_center_segmentation_fault_error_pop/) that you can reset the last panel using a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel ''
```

It does not solve the `Devices` section issue.

Comment: I have seen that problem on non-GNOME desktops - it's [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1831356).

Comment: Thank you very much it worked

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson apparently there is a fix released... wondering when we may get it

Comment: @learner I just recalled that maybe installing `hidpi-daemon` may solve `Devices` section issue. You may also try that.

Comment: @Alexandre: That "fix released" is about non-GNOME desktops (i.e. not the case for the OP of this question), and the "fix" consists of a proper error message instead of segfaulting. Not sure about the status of the issue on GNOME desktops.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson  I used "sudo apt-get install hidpi-daemon" to install  hidpi-daemon, now my Device is also accessible .                                                       May I know what was the issue,  I am entirely unfamiliar with ubuntu.  Thank you very much

Comment: @learner: Now I'm confused. That package does not exist in the Ubuntu archive, but only in the Pop!_OS PPA. Is Pop!_OS what you are using?

Comment: @Gunnar, No I am using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @learner: But.. To be able to install `hidpi-daemon` that way, you first added `ppa:system76/pop`, didn't you? If not I must be missing something...

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I added the ppa but I didn't install Pop!_Os, I was looking for a lighter version of desktop because my Ubuntu was really slow in loading applications even though my laptop is  a new one.

Comment: @learner: Ah, that may explain it. AFAIK g-c-c requires bot gnome-shell and mutter to work as expected, but `hidmi-damon` might be a way to work around that requirement.

Comment: This solution works for me in Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

try to take a screenshot of your screen, and look at the picture. If the setting is on the right side of the screen that means you have accidentally opened a join screen. You can search for turning a join screen from the terminal. Hope this would help.

Comment: May you edit your answer and explain a bit more about what a "join screen" is? Also, what you mean by "turning a join screen from terminal"? A screen shot may be helpful.

Comment: when I took a screenshot of my screen, it shows me that there were another that is functioning in which my settings windows are opened there. So what I am suggesting is that: first, take a screenshot of your screen and if you see an elonged photo of your screen that shows your settings window, if you see it then you can google the code to turn another screen off.